# android app can't receive packets set from arduino via wifi with sockets

Tags: android, networking, arduino

I am making an app that send message to an piece of hardware (arduino) using sockets but i cant receive any message back ?

```
new Thread(new Runnable() {

                @Override
                public void run() {
                    try {
                        client = new Socket(ipAddress, portNumber);
                        printwriter = new OutputStreamWriter(client

               .getOutputStream(), "ISO-8859-1");enter code here
                        printwriter.write(message);
                        printwriter.flush();
                        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(client.getInputStream()));
                        String line;

                        while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
                            line = br.readLine();

                        }
                        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),line,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        printwriter.close();
                        client.close();
                    }

                    catch (UnknownHostException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }).start();

            t.setText("done");
```

what happen is that when i send the message the it print on arduion but when the arduion send message back i see in the packet tracer app that it is actually send a packets but my app didn't capture it and put it in the Toast